# How to reindex magento2 in xampp?

Tags: php, magento2, reindex

I am trying to reindex magento2 in my localhost(xampp), but can't reindexing, this message is showing when type in command line, the image is

https://cloudup.com/cJmYZ3Uhkcy

i have also change advanced system setting in my computer, the image is

https://cloudup.com/c-Gpl03GMja

Any solution

Comment: Did you change the system setting before launching the command window?

Comment: yes, please see the second image, was it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below process to reindex from the command line.

At first please check which drive you have installed XAMPP. (Ex. C:). So if you have XAMPP installed in drive C:

go to command line (CMD) - type -

cd\

Now you will go to root drive C:

Now you have to go over on Magento2 root folder so you can use below command

cd  **C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2folder**

Now you are on your Magento2 root folder

Now type the following command

```
php bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

One Other method you can follow like this

1) Open Xampp control panel

2) Click on Shell button

3) Now you have to move on Magento2 root folder so same you can type the following command

cd  **C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2folder**

Now you are on your Magento2 root folder

Now type the following command

```
php bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install the composer on your system.It removes the dependency.
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

And then your index command will run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the htdocs then magento folder then right click and open xampp command prompt then run **php bin\magento indexer:reindex** this command.

Answer (score 0):

giving error because you have installed xampp in D Drive and never made your path for php.exe global.

solution 1: Make your path global.

solution 2: Manually write path of php.exe

correct command in your case:

```
d:\xampp\php\php.exe bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

instead of

```
php/bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

[image]

```
cd /
d:
cd d:\xampp\htdocs\magento
d:\xampp\php\php.exe bin\magento indexer:reindex
```